# Как можно сделать чтобы "div" растягивался на всю ширину и высоту страницы?

Tags: html, css

Вот сайт: http://cn01371.tmweb.ru, когда открываю с телефона, высота страницы увеличивается , из-за текста. Но div элемент c классом "global" ,который содержит в себе и "header" , и "main" не растягивается на новый размер страницы. Как можно сделать чтобы "div" растягивался на всю ширину и высоту страницы?

```css
body{
    background-image: url(/image/m_cyberpunk.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Montserrat Alternates', sans-serif;
}
.global{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    display:grid;
    grid-template-areas: 'part1 part2';
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
header{grid-area:part1;}
p{
    margin-bottom:10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
main{
    margin:auto;
}

/***************************************desktop menu***************************************/

.header{text-align:center;}
.desktop-menu{
    overflow: auto;
    height:610px;
    width: 300px;
    margin-left: 25px;
}
.wo{padding:0;}
.nav-li{
    list-style-type: none;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align:center;
   margin-bottom:20px;
}
.relate{
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:white;
    border: 4px solid white;
}
.relate-active{
    border: 4px solid  rgb(0, 140, 255);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 70px rgb(0, 140, 255);
    color: rgb(0, 140, 255);
}
.relate:hover{
    border: 4px solid  rgb(0, 140, 255);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 70px rgb(0, 140, 255);
    color: rgb(0, 140, 255);
}
/****************************************mobile menu****************************************/

.mobile-menu{
    display:none;
    overflow: auto;
}
.mobile-menu-line{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    height:5px;
    width:35px;
    background-color:black;
    right:10%;
    top:20px;
}
.mobile-menu-line::before, .mobile-menu-line::after{
    content: '';
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
    height:5px;
    width:35px;
    background-color:black;
}
.mobile-menu-line::before{
    transition-duration: 1s;
    top:-10px;
}
.mobile-menu-line::after{
    transition-duration: 1s;
    top:10px;
}
.mobile-menu-btn{
    margin-left:20px;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: green;
    cursor:pointer;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 70px green;
    align-self: center;
}
.mobile-menu-btn-active{
    margin-left:20px;
    grid-area: btn;
    align-self: center;
    background-color: red;
    transition: background-color 1s linear;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 70px red;
}
.mobile-menu-line-active::before{
    transition-duration:1s;
top:0px;
}
.mobile-menu-line-active::after{
    transition-duration:1s;
    top:0px;
    }
    .header-mobile{
        grid-area: h2;
        align-self: center;
    }
    .mobile-menu-line-active{
        transition-duration:1.5s;
        background-color: green;
    }
    .mobile-menu-wrapper{
        height: 100%;
        display:grid;
        grid-template-areas: 'h2 btn'
                             'menu menu'        ;
        
        left:-310px;
        transition: left 1s linear;
        width:310px;
        background-color: rgba(204, 0, 255, 0.1);
    }
    .mobile-menu-wrapper-active{
        display:grid;
        grid-template-areas: 'h2 btn'
                             'menu menu'        ;
    }
  /******************************** media for nav ********************************/
  @media(max-width:800px){
    .desktop-menu{
        display:none;
    }
    .mobile-menu{
        display:inline;
    }
    main{
        position: absolute;
        left:0px;
    }
    .mobile-menu-wrapper{
        position: absolute;
        left:-240px;
        transition: left 1s ease;
    }
    .mobile-menu-wrapper-active{
left:0px;
    }
    .nav-li-mobile{
width:200px ;
margin-bottom:5px;
    }
    main{
        margin-left:20px;
    }
  }
/**************************************content**************************************/
.tabs__pane {display:none;}
.tabs__pane_show {
display: block;
}  
.tabs__content{
    display:flex;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    line-height: 15px;
    left:100px;
    transition: left 0.5s linear;
}

/*content for mobile*/

.tabs__content-active{
left:300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="global">
<header></header>
<main class="tabs__content"></main>
</div>
```

Comment: Некошерно выходит ))) Для `.global` у вас прописано `position: absolute;`, А кто родитель? Если body, то где в нём `position: relative;`?

Comment: Да,я ещё когда выкладывал это заметил и задал `position:relative;` для body, но не стал здесь исправлять, потому что это всё равно не помогло.

Comment: А вот это странно. Так как перешёл я по вашей ссылке, открыл инспектор объектов в браузере и добавил эту запись для body/ И для мобильных устройств, как только окно браузера я достаточно заузил, всё отлично заработало. Оттого и написал вам комментарий выше.

Comment: попробовал добавить `z-index` к `position:absolute` и посмотрел результат в safari, chrome , opera - всё равно не работает. Так более того, с `position:relative` тёмный фон вообще пропадает ,но если `position:relative` убрать то фон заполняет весь экран, но не в том случае ,если размер страницы меняется.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо было обнулить дефолтный css